# Passing Field Name to Razor @helper in Webmatrix pages C#

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix, helper

This code obtains a listing of unique org names for display within my .cshtml page:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> data = db.Query("Select * from provider 
   where submitter_element = '210300'");  
                            //the 210300 could be any value passed to the query

var items = data.Select(i => new { i.org_name }).Distinct();
   foreach(var name in items){
     <text>@name.org_name<br></text>
```

The records in `data` are each unique themselves, but the data in each field contains the same values i.e. multiple providers have the same org_name.

I want to be able to reuse the `data` multiple times to create multiple unique lists.  I was hoping to pass this to a @helper for display.  To that end, I have the following:

```
@helper ListBoxDistinctDisplay(IEnumerable<dynamic> queryResult)
{  
   IEnumerable<dynamic> distinctItems = queryResult.Select(i => new { i.org_name }).Distinct();
   foreach(var listItem in distinctItems){
   <text>@listItem.org_name<br></text>
}
```

Then in my .cshtml page I do this:

```
@DisplayHelpers.ListBoxDistinctDisplay(data)
```

...and BINGO, I get my unique list on my "view" page.

The works perfectly, except as you see I am having to indicate .org_name within the helper.

My question is how can I pass the field name (org_name) into the helper so that my helper can be re-used no matter he field name?

OR...is there a totally different approach all together that I am unaware of?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Since you like to use dynamic, I'll stick with that.
You may want to pass selector:

```
@helper ListBoxDistinctDisplay(IEnumerable<dynamic> queryResult, Func<dynamic, dynamic> selector)
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> distinctItems = queryResult.Select(x => new {selectedField = selector(x)}).Distinct();
    foreach (var listItem in distinctItems)
    {
        <text>@listItem.selectedField<br/></text>
    }
}
```

Call it:

```
@DisplayHelpers.ListBoxDistinctDisplay(data, x => x.org_name)
```